# Is it possible to use "Save to Drive" button with the Firebase Storage public files (cors problem)?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-drive-api, cors, firebase-storage

I'm trying to do the following:

1. Save the file to my Firebase storage and get a public link to it.
2. Add a "Save to Drive" button on my website so users can save this file to their Google Drive.

I've already set these cors settings for the Storage:

```
[
    {
      "origin": ["*"],
      "method": ["GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"],
      "responseHeader": ["*"],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
    }
]
```

But after I try to save file using "Save to Drive" button, I get cors errors:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/{domain}/o/projects%2F-NXLt_SKMfg2aMASx9hu%2Fexport%2Ftmp_export.pdf?alt=media&token=e9336aa3-c827-423b-bd09-162c8d332f80'
> from origin 'http://localhost:8082' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Request header field cache-control is not allowed by
> Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

[Cors errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fh55C.png)

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that you can use Firebase http functions for this. Download from storage and than add it to response of your endpoint

```
exports.exportFile = onRequest({ cors: ["*"] }, async (req, res) => {

  // some code to get file

  const buffer = ... //get buffer of your file

  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
  res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename={your_filename}");
  res.send(buffer);
});
```

And then just add url to your "Save to Drive" button.

```
<div
  class="g-savetodrive"
  data-src="http://{domain}/.../exportFile"
  data-filename="{filename}"
  data-sitename=""
></div>
```